# How can I use pygi Webkit on a headless server install?

Tags: server, python, pygi, webkit

I have a set of scripts that works on my laptop that works fine as long as I'm booted in to an X session, but if I'm running on a headless server install I get loads of critical fails from Gtk.  I'm sure the solution is to use xvfb, but I can't find a working example.

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed [this article](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/) for running a Firefox-based test framework on a server earlier this year. The Xvfb-stuff is pretty simple, we just need to make sure to turn the access controls off so X doesn't get all uppity. Something like this should get you going:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
# run your gubbins
```

Though you should note that this isn't going to provide everything a real desktop session has. If you ever get into that situation (where you need a real desktop) it might be worth separating that out into a virtual machine on top of the server. A little less inefficient but miles more portable.

*Edit from Abraham:*
I wound up using the methodology, but I wanted it in a python management task.  My implementation did the same thing, but it looked more like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import subprocess, os
from multiprocessing import Process

def run():
    sub = Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(('Xvfb', ':10', '-ac',), ))
    sub.start()
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['DISPLAY'] = ":10"
    tasks = ('random','management','commands','thatneedDISPLAY:X')
    for task in tasks:
        p = subprocess.call(['python','manage.py',task],env=env)
    sub.terminate()

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseCommand.__init__(self)

    args = 'none'
    help = '''Run all daily tasks.'''

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        run()
```

Comment: Thanks @Oli.  You're a lifesaver.  Let me try it out before I accept to see if it works in my env.

Comment: Also, if you just need to run a single script, `xvfb-run -a script` will run the script in a session, without having to manually specify a DISPLAY, or hope you pick one that doesn't conflict with existing displays (in case you need to run multiple things under xvfb).

Comment: I'm running django management commands with subshell inception, so it's not exactly straightforward.  I was more hoping for import python-beast-mode-xvfb; python-beast-mode-xvfb.instance(webkit instance) or something, but it's fine.

Comment: @hbdgaf How so? Terminate doesn't kill-off descendant processes so it might be that X is forking out and being orphaned (but alive). http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate

Comment: Nevermind.  It worked.  I killed a run mid-run to troubleshoot something.  When you start naked and let it run xvfb works when run this way.